# Clear lag without joining world

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am currently playing a custom modpack with a friend, and we are mining cobblestone with a buildcraft quarry. Now the chest we are feeding the cobblestone into is full and we have a bunch of cobblestone laying on the ground. It is so much cobblestone that the server we are playing on immediately crashes when the chunk is loaded. I have downloaded the world and tried to play it in singleplayer. When joining the world it loaded for about a minute or so, then I could see a part of the world and a bunch of cobblestone on the ground, then the game crashed.

Is there any way to get rid of all that cobblestone without joining the world?

We are playing on forge 1.12.2.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, you need to be careful what mods/modpacks you use. Make sure to check the reviews and rating to prevent corruption of your world.

To solve your problem, there are multiple ways:

1. If you can get in the world for a few seconds, open the chat menu, and enter the following `/kill`. This will kill everything, including the cobblestone items, so make sure you have save inventory on.
2. Unfortunately, the only other option is to delete the world.

Comment: This is almost correct, but there are other options, such as NBT Explorer, or using a tick speed changer (may work).